# How to write custom data into an Array then read them from it?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to write individual numbers in an array, for example 9, 10, 11. Then read the numbers in a `for` cycle and work with the number? I have tried to understand this from the documentation, but have not been able to relate the examples there to this use case.

Please, write me a template for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array with `array.new_*()` function. You may want to use the keyword `var` with it to make it initialized only once.

Then you can use `array.push()` or `array.set()` to assign values to your array.

Get the length of the array with `array.size()`.

Use that length to loop over your array.

Access the items with `array.get()`.

Below example will push `bar_index` to an array and will display the last three bar indices.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var my_array = array.new_int()
array.push(my_array, bar_index)

len = array.size(my_array)

if (barstate.islast)
    if (len > 3)
        s = ""
        for i = len - 3 to len - 1
            num = array.get(my_array, i)
            s := s + str.tostring(num) + "\n"
        label.new(bar_index, high, s)
```

[image]

Comment:  Would you please look at it again? It seems no label displayed with the data in the array. (Copied your code without any modification.)

Comment: It works on my end. Try it on BTCUSD.

Comment: Would you mind to check it on GBPUSD? That's my key. Maybe a little different code is needed. (I don't see any flaws in the code above so I wouldn't get why…)

Comment: No problem there either.

Comment: On what timeframe are you running this? And what is your exchange?

Comment: 1H, Capitalcom. But actually, I want to store Support/Resistance levels (manually, for now) in this way, so that I can manage it somehow in a Strategy. So you don't specifically need to store the price history. (But, even my custom numbers was not stored/displayed.)

Comment: It is also there. Are you checking the last bar?

Comment: Yes, it's there now, I don't know how did I make it not working first time. But I can not re-interpret this template for my custom numbers. I posted another question with the actual case, simplified. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76774410/writing-custom-data-into-an-array-and-reading-back-them-with-direct-addressing