# Writing custom data into an array and reading back them with direct addressing. How to do it?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I know it's not the most elegant way to handle Support and Resistance values but it's good enough for me, for now.

Here's my code (based on [this working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76758119/how-to-write-custom-data-into-an-array-then-read-them-from-it/76760043)):

```
var SupportResistance = array.new_float()
array.push(SupportResistance, 1.29000)
array.push(SupportResistance, 1.29100)

var float SupRes1 = array.get(SupportResistance, 1) // Trying to read a value
line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, SupRes1, color=color.red, extend=extend.right)
```

For some reason, this results in vertical red lines, even though I shot the two example values ​​directly close to the real price.

**How can we read these values to use them as any numeric variables**?

Comment: Are you trying to draw a horizontal S&R line? Why are you using the `close` in `line.new()`?

Comment: ‍♂️ Please act like I didn't post the question…

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same value `bar_index` as `x1` and `x2`. That's why you get a vertical line.

What you need to do is to use `bar_index` and `bar_index + 1` as `x1` and `x2`, and use the same price level as `y1` and `y2`. This would draw a horizontal line.

```
line.new(bar_index, SupRes1, bar_index + 1, SupRes1, color=color.red, extend=extend.right)
```

Comment: Yeah, I realised it after your asking…  ‍♂️ It works now.